# Calculate $\frac{3\sin\alpha+2\tan\alpha}{\cot\alpha}$ if $\cos\alpha=\frac13$

Tags: trigonometry

> Calculate $\dfrac{3\sin\alpha+2\tan\alpha}{\cot\alpha}$ if $\cos\alpha=\dfrac13$ where $\alpha$ is an acute angle.

So I am trying to simplify the given expressions but I am stuck on $\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha(3\cos\alpha+2)}{\cos^2\alpha}.$ Can you give me a hint?

If we use that $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$ we can find $\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha,\tan\alpha,\cot\alpha$ but this is not the most rational approach, I think.

Comment: In what quadrant is the given angle?

Comment: $$\sin^2\alpha=1-\cos^2\alpha=?$$

Comment: We have not studied the unit circle. Alpha is an acute angle.

Comment: Try substitution $(sin)^2a$ as $1-(cos)^2a$

Comment: So we can assume that the angle is in the first quadrant? The reason why this matters is because of the value of the sine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac{3\sin\alpha+2\tan\alpha}{\cot\alpha} = \dfrac{3\sin^2\alpha \cos \alpha+2\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha} = \dfrac{3(1- \cos^2 \alpha) \cos \alpha+2(1- \cos^2 \alpha)}{\cos^2\alpha}$$

You should be able to conclude.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can I ask you what is the fastest approach from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{3\sin x+2\tan x}{\cot x}=(3\sin x+2\frac{\sin x}{\cos x})\cdot\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{3\sin^2 x}{\cos x}+\frac{2\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}= \\ =\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}(3\cos x+2)=\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x}(3\cos x+2)=\frac{1-\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{1}{9}}(3\cdot \frac{1}{3}+2)=24
$$

Comment: With $x = \alpha$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yes, obviously. You can write "x" faster than "\alpha"...

Answer (score -1):

Hint : $\dfrac{3\sin\alpha+2\tan\alpha}{\cot\alpha}=\dfrac{3\sin\alpha}{\cot\alpha}+\dfrac{2\tan\alpha}{\cot\alpha}$

But $\dfrac{\sin\alpha}{\cot\alpha}=\frac{1-\cos(\alpha)^2}{\cos(\alpha)}$ and $\dfrac{\tan\alpha}{\cot\alpha}=\frac{1-\cos(\alpha)^2}{\cos(\alpha)^2}$ (why ?)

Comment: I don't understand why my hint is considered as useless...